# How to get COUNT of a range between 2 columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, count

```
Table:

Staff  | StartingTime |  EndingTime  | starthour   | endhour
-------------------------------------------------------------
10     |     0813     |    1610      |    08       |    16 
20     |     0910     |    1224      |    09       |    12
30     |     1132     |    1706      |    11       |    17
40     |     1311     |    2110      |    13       |    21
50     |     1533     |    2230      |    15       |    22
```

The first 2 time columns are nvarchar(4) and I derived the last 2 columns with `LEFT(field, 2)` to get the hours.

I need to get a count of the number of staff that were working for each hour. It will need to by dynamic as I will never know the time ranges. Right now I'm just trying to get this working for a single day, but eventually I need it broken out by day.

Expected results:

```
Hour  |  Staff 
------------------
8     |    1
9     |    2
10    |    2
11    |    3
12    |    3
13    |    4
14    |    4
15    |    5
..
19    |    2
etc..
```

This is on Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

Comment: So if you  need it broken out by day there must be a date part somewhere?

Comment: And why are you storing the time part as a string?

Comment: I have no control, it comes from a time clock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Recursive CTE` to generate Hours between `Min starthour` and `Max endhour`

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
  (Staff     INT,starthour INT,endhour   INT )

INSERT #temp
VALUES (10,08,16 ),(20,09,12),(30,11,17),
       (40,13,21),(50,15,22)

DECLARE @max_hr INT =(SELECT Max(endhour)
  FROM   #temp);

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Min(starthour) [hours]
         FROM   #temp
         UNION ALL
         SELECT [hours] + 1
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  [hours] < @max_hr)
SELECT Count(Staff),
       [hours]
FROM   cte a
       JOIN #temp t
         ON a.[hours] BETWEEN t.starthour AND t.endhour
GROUP  BY [hours]
```

Comment: I got this one working after CASTing the 2 digit hours,

Comment: I must admit that this solution is better tahn I previously submitted.
More elegant and more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way of doing it. However, if you need it broken out by day, you need to add an extra column in your table for indicating the day, and you should add that column to the table variable I created as well.

```
    DECLARE @Hours TABLE
    (
      hour varchar(2),
      total int
    )
    DECLARE @I INT 
    SET @I = 0
    WHILE @I < 24
    begin
        INSERT INTO @Hours VALUES (RIGHT('0' + CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(2)),2), 0)
        SET @I = @I + 1
    end 


    DECLARE @starthour VARCHAR(2)
    DECLARE @endhour VARCHAR(2)
    DECLARE cur CURSOR
    FOR SELECT starthour, endhour FROM WorkTime
    OPEN cur
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur
    INTO @starthour, @endhour
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        UPDATE @hours
        SET total = total + 1
        WHERE hour BETWEEN @starthour AND @endhour
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @starthour, @endhour
    end
    CLOSE cur
    DEALLOCATE cur

SELECT * FROM @hours
WHERE total <> 0
```

### OUTPUT

```
hour    total
08      1
09      2
10      2
11      3
12      3
13      3
14      3
15      4
16      4
17      3
18      2
19      2
20      2
21      2
22      1
```

Comment: As you can see, the output differs from the expected results you posted, but I suppose that the results that you posted were simply for explanation purposes and not intended to be 100% correct

Comment: That was quick. I'll give this a try tomorrow. Appreciate the help, this was giving me fits.